# Get td contain table from library simplehtmldom

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

simple_html_dom does not work in page "https://eldni.com/buscar-por-dni?dni=44626399"

```
<?php
include_once './simple_html_dom./HtmlWeb.php';
use simplehtmldom\HtmlWeb;

// get DOM from URL or file
$doc = new HtmlWeb();
$html = $doc->load('https://eldni.com/buscar-por-dni?dni=44626399');

foreach($html->find('td') as $e)
    echo $e->plaintext . '<br>' . PHP_EOL;
?>
```

I want td plain text of the "td" table.

Comment: Which for of the library are you using? And what is the current output of your code? If this is **exactly** the code you're trying to execute, I suspect your `include` statement has a typo (an extra `.` character) in it.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, i'm using this library: https://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/files/simplehtmldom/2.0-RC1/.

Comment: For the include, i'm using "." for the server's directory but it works for another aplications so i dont think it is. Nothing output, because the page is reloading more than 1 minute and never ends, and then it stops when time's out.